# Run Worker Service on Mac Os

Tags: c#, macos, .net-6.0, launchd, worker-service

I have created a Worker Service with .Net 6, I have published it via folder profile for Mac OS, Now in Windows I can create a service using `SC CREATE`, how do I achieve the same on Mac OS.
I have tried `launchd` but nothing happens no error or any log.
This is my plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.NYC.DOB</string>
    <key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>NYC DOB</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>             
        <string>Applications/DOB/NYC</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>out.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>error.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I have used the following commands to run the service

```
sudo launchctl load /Applications/DOB/org.NYC.DOB.plist
sudo launchctl start org.NYC.DOB
```

Commands are executed successfully but nothing happens.